# Using different raid partitions with docker

Tags: docker

I have a Linux (Ubuntu) machine with a partition on an SSD raid and a partition on an HDD raid. I want to put my docker containers with high traffic (like a database) on the SSD part and the other containers on the cheaper HDD part. I can't find an answer here or on other sides. Is there a possibility?

Answer (score 2):

Docker itself doesn't provide that level of control over Docker storage on a per container basis.

You can use the [devicemapper](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/) storage driver and use a specific raid logical volume for the container file systems. There's no way to choose between multiple storage devices at container run time, or via some policy.

Docker does have [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/) that can be added to a container and [volume plugins](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_volume/) to use different storage backends for volumes. These can controlled on a per container basis.

There is an [LVM volume plugin](https://github.com/projectatomic/docker-lvm-plugin). You could assign SSD's to a lvm volume 
 group and mount data volumes from that in any container you want the extra write performance in.

Another option would be to run multiple Docker daemons, one with each storage configuration, that would be difficult to maintain.